# How can I assign a weight for frequency score to a graph's edge using Graph::Easy

Tags: python, perl, graph

How do I assign a weight or frequency score to an graph's edge using Graph::Easy?

I have a list of bigrams and their frequencies. I can easily create a (mathematical) graph of only the bigrams using Graph::Easy. The output is exactly what I desire. But when I try to "set_attribute" I get an error that says, "'frequency' is not a valid attribute name". What am I doing wrong? Using Graph::Easy, how do I make frequency a valid attribute?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# graph.pl - given a list of bigrams and their frequencies, output graphml

# require
use Graph::Easy;
use strict;

# initialize
my $graph = Graph::Easy->new;

# process the data
while ( <DATA> ) {

    # parse
    chop;
    my ( $nodes, $frequency ) = split( "\t", $_ );
    my ( $source, $target )   = split( ' ', $nodes );

    # update the graph
    my $edge = $graph->add_edge( $source, $target );

    # error happen here
    $edge->set_attribute( 'frequency', $frequency );

}

# output & done
print $graph->as_graphml();
exit;


# a set of bigrams and their frequencies
__DATA__
cds classroom   4
maximum registration    4
may want    3
anomalies within    2
resulting analysis  2
participants may    2
corpus without  2
journal articles    2
quickly learn   2
active reading  2
text mining     2
literally count     2
find patterns   2
14 million  2
digital humanities  2
humanities research     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "best" answer for me is to not use Graph::Easy but instead use a Python module, [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# graph.py - given a CSV file of a specific shape, output graphml


# configure
DATA  = './data.csv'
GRAPH = './data.graphml'
LABEL = 'frequency'

# require
import networkx as nx
import csv

# initialize
g = nx.DiGraph()

# read the data
with open( DATA, 'r' ) as f :

    # initialize
    r = csv.reader( f, delimiter='\t')

    # process each record
    for source, target, frequency in r :

        # sanity check
        if len( source ) == 0 or len( target ) == 0 : continue

        # update the graph
        g.add_edge( source, target )    
        g[ source ][ target ][ LABEL ] = frequency

# output & done
nx.write_graphml( g, GRAPH )
exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

I played a bit with this module and it seems it doesn't accept arbitrary "attributes" but only a certain set of predefined ones.
Apparently 'frequency' is none of them.

I picked a sample from the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/lib/Graph/Easy.pm) and replaced your

```
$edge->set_attribute( 'frequency', $frequency );
```

with

```
$edge->set_attribute( 'label', $frequency );
```

as they often mention `label` in the examples.

```
print $graph->as_ascii();
```

then printed:

```
+--------------+  2   +--------------+
|      14      | ---> |   million    |
+--------------+      +--------------+
+--------------+  2   +--------------+  2   +----------+
|   digital    | ---> |  humanities  | ---> | research |
+--------------+      +--------------+      +----------+
+--------------+  2   +--------------+  3   +----------+
| participants | ---> |     may      | ---> |   want   |
+--------------+      +--------------+      +----------+
...
```

Is that what you were after?

---

Eventually I found the [complete documentation](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/index.html) for Graph::Easy. The [Attributes section](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/attributes.html) lists the allowed attributes. I'm pretty sure there is a way to have *custom attributes* because the module has a method [`get_custom_attributes`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Graph-Easy/lib/Graph/Easy.pm#get_custom_attributes()).

Comment: Alas, after a bit of an email exchange with the developer, I don't think it is possible to add arbitrary attributes to edges using Graph::Easy. Based on my experience, Graph::Easy is more about outputting graphs as opposed to generating graphml/XML.

Comment: The Python module -- [pygraphml](http://hadim.fr/pygraphml/) -- may be more suited to what I desire.

Comment: @ericleasemorgan Ah, ok. That looks reasonable. As said, I just played a bit around and wasn't aware that you wanted to create XML. Attributes makes sense there. Never mind. And thank you for showing me another interesting module. :-)